# Iis it possible to join 2 tables without a common column/primary key between them?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 datasets about payments [table 1 and 2]. I am using BigQuery to arrive at a specific output.

I am not sure what columns to use as primary key to left join the table 2.

[image]

Required output:

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: There isn't anything to join on. Your table2 contains dirty data, you need to clean it first. How you do that depends on what the data *should* look like, how it got dirty, your own business rules, etc, etc. *Then* you can join on name, address and city.

Comment: Perhaps `UNION ALL` makes more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below simple approach

```
select * from table1 t1 
full outer join table2 t2
on regexp_replace(lower(to_json_string(struct(t1.name, t1.address, t1.city))), r'\W', '')
 = regexp_replace(lower(to_json_string(struct(t2.name, t2.address, t2.city))), r'\W', '')
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]